# Select column names with index

Tags: php, mysql

Consider the following SQL

```
SHOW INDEX FROM table1
```

This will print out column names that serve as indexes for table1.

I am wondering if it is possible to embed a lookup like this inside of another query, for example:

```
SELECT (index column names on table1) FROM table1 WHERE ...
```

Is there a way to select these column names for use in such a query?

Comment: Uh, I don't get the question.  Your second sentence seems to answer the first sentence.  What other information are you looking for?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to get the data from a (any) column that has an index? Why?

Comment: I would like to the name of the column name which has the index in my php code as a variable

Comment: He wants the data from the primary key column, presumably without knowing the primary key column's name in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't subquery `SHOW`(refer to [SubQueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) for allowed statements in subqueries) , use two queries:

> //get the column
>    $q = mysql_query("SHOW INDEX FROM table");

and

> // use the column
>    $result = mysql_query("SELECT ".mysql_result($q,0,'Column_name')." FROM table ...");

For safe-check-sake you should **check if there *is* an index** and **decide which index to use in case you have more than one**

```
 //check for 0, 1 or more indexes
 switch(mysql_num_rows($q)){  
 case 0:
    echo 'no index';  
    break;  
 case 1:  
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT ".mysql_result($q,0,'Column_name')." FROM table ...");  
    break;  
 default:  
    echo 'more than one index';  
    break;
 }
```

You can choose an index by using the second argument of mysql_result like so:

> // chooses index nr.2
>   $result = mysql_query("SELECT ".mysql_result($q,**1**,'Column_name')." FROM table ...");

Comment: I am finding this to be the case. I've tried putting it in variables, too, and no dice. However, I cannot find anything in the docs (or even a blog) that mentions this. Do you have any source on this? It seems like undocumented behavior.

Comment: @Chris As I recall in MySQL manual under `SELECT` or some chapter about subqueries it is mentioned that `SHOW` queries cannot appear in subqueries. There are a few statements that aren't allowed in subqueries.

Comment: @JDuarteDJ The first query does not return anything. So I am seeing the Warning for the second query: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: The first query SHOULD return something,  I tested it but it was you that said `This will print out column names that serve as indexes for table1.` Did you replace `table` by your own table name? Does the table ACTUALLY have an index?

Comment: @JDuarteDJ: Sorry, that did work. something was wrong in my db connection

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several stages, as suggested, since you have PHP available to script. You can also accomplish this using only a query (from command line, for instance) by using the `information_schema` table and prepared statements, as follows:

```
SET @COLNAME = (SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` WHERE  `TABLE_SCHEMA` = "myDatabaseName" AND `TABLE_NAME` = "myTable" AND `COLUMN_KEY` = "pri");

SET @QRY = CONCAT("SELECT ", @COLNAME , " FROM `myTable`");

PREPARE stmnt FROM @QRY ;
EXECUTE stmnt;
```

This, of course, requires that the query user has permission to the information schema table as well as the target table.

Here is a small example of this at work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c753/2

To accomplish this in PHP, you'll have to break it up into steps as has been suggested in other answers; PDO at least does not seem to want to handle this query if passed as a single string.

**Documentation**

- MySQL Prepared Statements - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/prepare.html
- MySQL User-Defined Variables - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html
- MySQL information schema table - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tables-table.html

Comment: Overcomplicated for the target user.

Comment: Revenge dow nvoting is generally frowned upon.

Comment: This is not "revenge down voting", it was clearly explained in my previous comment to this answer! Besides it has been you that "revenge down voted" one of my questions!

Comment: I don't think so. "Overcomplicated for the target user" is ridiculous. Whose assessment is that, yours? Who put you in the position to make that assessment? Who is the "target user"? You've abused the voting system because you're mad about something. Just stop.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of answering this question, I'll use `mydb.mytable`.

First of all, a table could have more than one index.

You can find out all the indexes a table has from [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/statistics-table.html).

```
SELECT DISTINCT index_name IndexName FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE table_schema='mydb' AND table_name='mytable';
```

You will have to choose which index you want from `mydb.mytable`.

Let's say the index is called `myindex`.

The next thing you need is the [**GROUP_CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to create a comma-separated list of column names. Putting it all together, you should be able to craft the query like this:

```
SET @mydb = 'mydatabase';
SET @mytb = 'mytable';
SET @mynx = 'myindex';
SET @dbtb = CONCAT(@mydb,'.',@mytb);
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name)
INTO @IndexColumns
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE table_schema=@mydb
AND table_name=@mytb
AND index_name=@mynx;
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ',@IndexColumns,' FROM ',@dbtb) INTO @sqlstmt;
SELECT @sqlstmt;
```

## LIVE EXAMPLE

### THE TABLE

```
mysql> show create table wflow_report\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: wflow_report
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `wflow_report` (
  `organization_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `candidate_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `workflow_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `workflow_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orderid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `recorded_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date_applied` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `delta` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'O',
  `hiring_manager` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `recruiter` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `race` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `office_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `department_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `source_code` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `wfreport_officeDept_Idx` (`candidate_id`,`workflow_id`,`office_id`,`department_id`,`organization_id`,`source_code`,`status`),
  KEY `wfreport_RecHM_Idx` (`candidate_id`,`workflow_id`,`recruiter`,`hiring_manager`,`organization_id`,`source_code`,`status`),
  KEY `wfreport_Date_Idx` (`candidate_id`,`recorded_date`,`date_applied`,`workflow_id`,`organization_id`,`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

### THE QUERY FORMATION

```
SET @mydb = 'resumedirect';
SET @mytb = 'wflow_report';
SET @mynx = 'wfreport_officeDept_Idx';
SET @dbtb = CONCAT(@mydb,'.',@mytb);
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name)
INTO @IndexColumns
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE table_schema=@mydb
AND table_name=@mytb
AND index_name=@mynx;
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ',@IndexColumns,' FROM ',@dbtb) INTO @sqlstmt;
SELECT @sqlstmt;
```

### THE OUTPUT

```
mysql> SET @mydb = 'resumedirect';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @mytb = 'wflow_report';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @mynx = 'wfreport_officeDept_Idx';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @dbtb = CONCAT(@mydb,'.',@mytb);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name)
    -> INTO @IndexColumns
    -> FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
    -> WHERE table_schema=@mydb
    -> AND table_name=@mytb
    -> AND index_name=@mynx;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ',@IndexColumns,' FROM ',@dbtb) INTO @sqlstmt;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @sqlstmt;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @sqlstmt                                                                                                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SELECT candidate_id,workflow_id,office_id,department_id,organization_id,source_code,status FROM resumedirect.wflow_report |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I will leave it to you to append the WHERE clause you want and implement it in PHP.

## Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score -1):

try something like this instead?

```
SELECT Name FROM Table WHERE Id='target id'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with some php help

```
    $query = "SHOW INDEX FROM YOURTABLE" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);//$link is the connection to mysql
    $count = mysqli_num_row(result);
    //check index
    if(empty($count)){
    $Dataid=array();//no indexes
    }elseif($count==1){//One index
      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
      $id = $row['Column_name']; 

      $query_select = "SELECT `$id` FROM `YOURTABLE`";
      $result_select = mysqli_query($link, $query_select);
      while($row_select=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_select)){
        $Dataid[]=$row_select;
      }
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($Dataid);
        echo '</pre>';
  }else{//many indexes
    while($row =  mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $Index[]=$row['Column_name'];
      }

    //list all indexes, you can call them by their key($Index[0],$Index[1]...)
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($Index);
    echo '</pre>';

  }
```

Comment: @JDuarteDJ you post first the answer, when i wrote my answer i didnt see your post, i saw after...

Comment: Yes, he's mad and getting revenge at us for his posting of nonfunctional code. I know... irrational.

Comment: Actually, no. I meant your answer wasn't explanatory enough and not to mention inefficient. That is why the down vote. For politeness sake I would remove it but I'm not allowed, so if a mod reads this please remove the downvote. Or if you edit your answer. Thanks.